# Is it possible to pattern match on type String and get the result trimmed?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Say I have code like this:

```
def isCryptoExample(parts: Seq[Any]): Boolean = parts match {
    case List(loneWord)                      => false
    case List(subject: String, verb: String) =>
      ((subject.trim startsWith "Alice") || (subject.trim startsWith "Bob")) &&
      ((verb.trim == "encrypts") || (verb.trim == "decrypts"))
  }
```

Those repeated `.trim` calls are ugly, but adding statements like `val subjectTrimmed = subject.trim` is an almost as ugly workaround. Is there any way to get the pattern match variables trimmed immediately in the case statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own `Trimmed` extractor:

```
object Trimmed {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[String] = Some(s.trim)
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
def isCryptoExample(parts: Seq[Any]): Boolean = parts match {
    case List(loneWord)      => false
    case List(Trimmed(subject), Trimmed(verb)) =>
      ((subject startsWith "Alice") || (subject startsWith "Bob")) &&
      ((verb == "encrypts") || (verb == "decrypts"))
  }
```

Daniel Westheide has [an excellent introduction](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html) to what extractors are and how they work.

Answer (score 2):

A couple more alternatives to go with Emil's:

```
val Subject = """\s*(Alice|Bob)\s*""".r
val Verb = """\s*(encrypts|decrypts)\s*""".r
List("Alice", "  encrypts  ") match {
  case List(Subject(s), Verb(v)) => true
  case _ => false
}

val ss = List("Alice", "Bob")
val vs = List("encrypts", "decrypts")
List("Alice", "  encrypts  ") match {
  case (List(s, v)) if ss.contains(s.trim) && vs.contains(v.trim) => true
  case _ => false
}
```